# Statistical problem related to product lifespan

Tags: bayesian, estimation, approximation

I design electronics, and while I have some basic education in the principles of statistics, I don't believe I'm qualified to determine whether this problem is tractable as it was posed to me. So I turn to this community...

Suppose at some point in the past, $X$ number of some consumer product was produced per year. Production of this product ceased in year $Y$, and we now find ourselves $Z$ years into the future away from when production ceased.

Obviously, products being what they are, after any appreciable length of time a certain number of them will have failed such that they are no longer functional and have been discarded. Is it possible to perform a statistical best guess based on some data as to how many instances of the product are still in functional condition "in the wild" and how many have been discarded? If so, what method would be used and what data would be required to make a good estimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attack this problem with **Survival Analysis**. You would need a sample of historical survival (lifetime) data of your broken device in order to construct a hazard function using the Kapplan-Meier estimator or Cox regression. You will then pass parameters Y and Z as time points into that function and it'll give you the probability of survival at time Z for a device that was built at time Y. This is equivalent to estimating the proportion of devices built at time Y, surviving into time Z. You could then add some confidence intervals to that proportion and estimate the number of surviving devices for the entire population. It's not a simple process but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any canonical text on "Survival Analysis" that you would recommend? Some of this is Greek to me, but it would make an interesting learning exercise.

I'm not sure what I have access to that could be used as a sample of "historical survival data" in this case. Is there anything that could be learned from, say, a sample of the serial numbers/manufacture dates of surviving units?

Comment: It's quite a common technique in biostatistics and engineering. You should read [this guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/survival-analysis.html) to get a better understanding of the process. You must have some historical data of older devices where the length of their lifespan was recorded (from creation to hazard). If all your data is on devices which are still "alive" then you can't really infer anything about their theoretical life expectancy and their rate of decay...

Comment: Well if you've got none of that then you could use an appropriate theoretical distribution (such as the Weibull or Exponential distributions) as your hazard function to do the same thing. This would be less accurate but much simpler. Plus, if you don't have the data then there's really not much of a choice.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was wondering if perhaps there were a way to infer lifespan based on the manufacture date of devices still in existence, like say noting there are $A$ number of devices from 1978 active in a current sampling, while there are $B$ devices from 1983, where $A < B$.

Comment: If you use a theoretical distribution to model your hazard function then you don't really need any data on your devices, you only need to plug time points Y and Z into your function to get the corresponding density value.